# matlab feature selection for regression models

Tags: matlab, feature-selection

I have a dataset of videos with x1,..,x24 features, and y as a score. I want to perform feature selection to reduce the error rate. I've found `sequentialfs` in Matlab but it's for classification.

Is there any feature selection function for regression? If it is could you provide an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `sequentialfs` is for classification and regression, too.

> Typical loss measures include sum of squared errors for regression
>   models (sequentialfs computes the mean-squared error in this case),
>   and the number of misclassified observations for classification models
>   (sequentialfs computes the misclassification rate in this case).